# Too many script requests when creating table with indicators

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I've been trying to write an indicator in the form of a table that lists a symbol, it's Faustmann ratio, and it's Spitznaegel ROIC with different colors depending on the ranges these indicators are in. I'm taking most of this from previous scripts others have written for these indicators. Below is my script.

```
//@version=5
indicator('test screener', overlay=true)

////////////
// INPUTS //
col_width = input.float(6, title = "Column Width (%)")
scr_numb  = input.int(3, title = "Screen #", tooltip = '1 - rightmost screener', minval = 1)
 
/////////////
// SYMBOLS // 
u01 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's01')
u02 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's02')
u03 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's03')

s01 = input.symbol('CF',  group = 'Symbols', inline = 's01')
s02 = input.symbol('CLF',  group = 'Symbols', inline = 's02')
s03 = input.symbol('DFS',  group = 'Symbols', inline = 's03')


//////////////////
// CALCULATIONS //

// Get only symbol
only_symbol(s) => 
    array.get(str.split(s, ":"), 1)

sfm(s) =>
    cur_assets = request.financial(s, "TOTAL_CURRENT_ASSETS", "FQ")
    net_ppe = request.financial(s, "PPE_TOTAL_NET", "FQ")
    cap_leases = request.financial(s, "CAPITAL_OPERATING_LEASE_OBLIGATIONS", "FQ")
    long_term_investments = request.financial(s, "LONG_TERM_INVESTMENTS", "FQ")
    cur_liabilities = request.financial(s, "TOTAL_CURRENT_LIABILITIES", "FQ")
    cash = request.financial(s, "CASH_N_EQUIVALENTS", "FQ")
    invested_capital = cur_assets[0] + net_ppe[0] + cap_leases[0] + long_term_investments[0] - cur_liabilities[0] - cash[0]

    shares_outstanding = request.financial(s, "TOTAL_SHARES_OUTSTANDING", "FQ")
    common_market_cap = shares_outstanding[0] * close

    long_term_debt = request.financial(s, "LONG_TERM_DEBT", "FQ")
    preferred_stock = request.financial(s, "PREFERRED_STOCK_CARRYING_VALUE", "FQ")
    net_worth = invested_capital + cash[0] - long_term_debt[0] - cap_leases[0] - preferred_stock[0]
    fm = common_market_cap / net_worth

    [fm, invested_capital]

sroic(s, ic) =>
    var ebit_ttm = float(na)
    var ebit_q1 = 0.0
    var ebit_q2 = 0.0
    var ebit_q3 = 0.0
    var ebit_q4 = 0.0

    ebit_series_filled = request.financial(s, "EBIT", "FQ", ignore_invalid_symbol = false)
    ebit_series_fq = request.financial(s, "EBIT", "FQ", ignore_invalid_symbol = true)
    ebit_series_fy = request.financial(s, "EBIT", "FY", ignore_invalid_symbol = false)

    if not na(ebit_series_fq[0])
        ebit_q4 := ebit_q3
        ebit_q3 := ebit_q2
        ebit_q2 := ebit_q1
        ebit_q1 := ebit_series_fq[0]
        ebit_ttm := ebit_q1 + ebit_q2 + ebit_q3 + ebit_q4
    else if na(ebit_series_filled[0]) and not na(ebit_series_fy[0])
        ebit_ttm := ebit_series_fy[0]

    roic = ebit_ttm / ic
    

// Security call
[sfm01, ic01] = request.security(s01, timeframe.period, sfm(s01))
[sfm02, ic03] = request.security(s02, timeframe.period, sfm(s02))
[sfm03, ic02] = request.security(s03, timeframe.period, sfm(s03))

sroic01 = request.security(s01, timeframe.period, sroic(s01, ic01))
sroic02 = request.security(s02, timeframe.period, sroic(s02, ic02))
sroic03 = request.security(s03, timeframe.period, sroic(s03, ic03))


////////////
// ARRAYS //
s_arr   = array.new_string(0)
u_arr   = array.new_bool(0)
sfm_arr = array.new_float(0)
sroic_arr = array.new_float(0)

// Add Symbols 
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s01))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s02))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s03))

// FLAGS 
array.push(u_arr, u01)
array.push(u_arr, u02)
array.push(u_arr, u03)

// SFM
array.push(sfm_arr, sfm01)
array.push(sfm_arr, sfm02)
array.push(sfm_arr, sfm03)

// SROIC
array.push(sroic_arr, sroic01)
array.push(sroic_arr, sroic02)
array.push(sroic_arr, sroic03)

///////////
// PLOTS //
n_symbols = 3
indicator_1 = 'SFM-HOMIES'
indicator_2 = 'SROIC-HOMIES'
sfm_os  = input.float(0, title = "SFM Overbought", group = "Indicators")
sfm_ob  = input.float(1, title = "SFM Oversold",   group = "Indicators")

sroic_lower  = input.float(0.2, title = "SROIC Lower Limit",   group = "Indicators")
sroic_lower2  = input.float(0.5, title = "SROIC Lower Limit2",   group = "Indicators")

var tbl = table.new(position.top_right, 3, n_symbols+1, frame_color=#151715, frame_width=1, border_width=2, border_color=color.new(color.white, 100))
if barstate.islast
    table.cell(tbl, 0, 0, 'Symbol', width = col_width, text_halign = text.align_center, bgcolor = color.gray, text_color = color.white, text_size = size.small)
    table.cell(tbl, 1, 0, indicator_1, width = col_width, text_halign = text.align_center, bgcolor = color.gray, text_color = color.white, text_size = size.small)
    table.cell(tbl, 2, 0, indicator_2, width = col_width, text_halign = text.align_center, bgcolor = color.gray, text_color = color.white, text_size = size.small)
    
    for i = 0 to n_symbols-1
        if array.get(u_arr, i)
            table.cell(tbl, 0, i + 1, array.get(s_arr, i), text_halign = text.align_center, bgcolor = color.gray, text_color = color.white, text_size = size.small)
            
            sfm_col = array.get(sfm_arr, i) > sfm_ob ? color.red : array.get(sfm_arr, i) < sfm_os ? color.red : array.get(sfm_arr, i) < sfm_ob and array.get(sfm_arr, i) > sfm_os ? color.green : #aaaaaa 
            table.cell(tbl, 1, i + 1, str.tostring(array.get(sfm_arr, i), "#.##"), text_halign = text.align_center, bgcolor = sfm_col, text_color = color.white, text_size = size.small)

            sroic_col  = array.get(sroic_arr, i) < sroic_lower ? color.red : array.get(sroic_arr, i) >= sroic_lower ? color.yellow : array.get(sroic_arr, i) >= sroic_lower2 ? color.green : #aaaaaa 
            table.cell(tbl, 2, i + 1, str.tostring(array.get(sroic_arr, i), "#.##"), text_halign = text.align_center, bgcolor = sroic_col, text_color = color.white, text_size = size.small)
```

When trying to display this table, I get the following error:
`Script requests too many securities: 42. The limit is 40`. I'm not entirely sure how to rectify this and was wondering if others had any ideas. The line that seems problematic is below:

```
table.cell(tbl, 2, i + 1, str.tostring(array.get(sroic_arr, i), "#.##"), text_halign = text.align_center, bgcolor = sroic_col, text_color = color.white, text_size = size.small)
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

I tried implementing the above code, but I'm not sure of a better way to optimize the security calls.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is a limitation. You can read about it [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/Error_messages.html?highlight=request%20securiti#script-requesting-too-many-securities)

you need to limit the use securities